# I have a uniformly convergent sequence of functions known to be analytic at a single point. Is the limit also analytic at this point?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to solve the following problem from Lang's Complex Analysis book:

> Let $f$ be analytic on an open set $U$, let $a \in U$, and $f'(a) \ne 0$. Show that
>
> $$\frac {2 \pi i} {f'(a)} = \int_\gamma \frac {dz} {f(z) - f(a)}$$
>
> where $\gamma$ is a small circle centered at $a$.

What I tried was the following:

> Use the inverse mapping theorem to shrink $U$ to a small neighborhood $a$ where $f$ is invertible, and let $\gamma$ lie in this neighborhood. Define the family of functions $g_w : U \to \mathbb C$, where
>
> $$g_w(z) =
>     \begin{cases}
>       \frac {z - w} {f(z) - f(w)} & \text{if } z \ne w \\
>       \frac 1 {f'(w)}             & \text{if } z = w \\
>     \end{cases}
>   $$
>
> Every $g_w$ is analytic at every $z \ne w$. In particular, $g_a$ is analytic at every $z \ne a$. Now take a convergent sequence $w_n$ to $a$. Then the sequence $g_{w_n}$ is also (uniformly) convergent to $g_a$. **Every $g_{w_n}$ is analytic at $a$, hence so is the limit $g_a$.**
>
> Hence by Cauchy's integral formula, we have the desired result:
>
> $$\frac {2 \pi i} {f'(a)} = \int_\gamma \frac {g_a(z)} {z - a} dz = \int_\gamma \frac {dz} {f(z) - f(a)}$$

I am not convinced about the highlighted step. I have previously proved that, if $f_n \to f$ is a uniformly convergent family of analytic functions in $U$, the limit $f$ is also analytic in $U$. But, when I took a uniformly convergent sequence of functions $g_{w_n} \to g_a$, there was no common set in which all $g_{w_n}$'s are analytic. How could I fix this proof?

Comment: This is all a bit unnecessary: $g_a$ is analytic, for the same reason as every other $g_w$ is analytic. You don't need to consider any other $g_w$s at all.

Comment: I need $g_a$ to be analytic at $a$, which is not obvious (to me, at least). How would I prove that?

Comment: It says "$g(w)$ is analytic at every $z \neq w$". Actually you don't have to exclude $z$ at all. $g_w$ has  limiting value as $z \to w$ and it has been assigned exactly this limiting value at $z$.

Comment: I'm sorry for being dense, perhaps I'm missing something really obvious, but I don't see how “$g_w$ has a limiting value as $z \to w$” alone justifies “$g_w$ is analytic at $w$ as well”.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the right way to solve it.

Let $f(z) = \sum_k c_k (z - a)^k$ be the power series expansion of $f$ around $a$. By hypothesis, $f(z) - f(a)$ has order 1, so there exists a power series $g(z)$ of order 0 such that $(z-a) g(z) = f(z) - f(a)$. Of course, it is $g(z) = \sum_k c_{k+1} (z-a)^k$. This series has a multiplicative inverse $h(z)$. Moreover, $h(z)$ is convergent, because $g(z)$ is convergent, because $f(z)$ is convergent. Hence $h(z)$ is the power series expansion of an analytic function in a neighborhood of $a$. It is not hard to see that this function is

$$
h(z) =
  \begin{cases}
    \frac {z - a} {f(z) - f(a)} & \text{if } z \ne a \\
    \frac 1 {f'(a)}             & \text{if } z = a   \\
  \end{cases}
$$

Hence, using Cauchy's integral formula, we have the desired result:

$$
\frac 1 {2 \pi i} \int_\gamma \frac {dz} {f(z) - f(a)}
  = \frac 1 {2 \pi i} \int_\gamma \frac {h(z) dz} {z - a}
  = W(\gamma, a) h(a)
  = \frac 1 {f'(a)}
$$